# Solve $\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ax-x^2\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{a^2-2ax\sin(\theta)+x^2}}d\theta dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Solve
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ax-x^2\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{a^2-2ax\sin(\theta)+x^2}}d\theta dx$$
This integral is from the following paper : [Frictional coupling between sliding and spinning motion](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0210024.pdf)
and can be understood as an integration of unit vector field parallel to the velocity of a spinning disk which is sliding with the speed of $a$ over a unit disk. The evaluation of the integral is claimed to be

$$\frac{4}{3}\frac{(a^2+1)E(a)+(a^2-1)K(a)}{a}$$
for $a<1$, and

$$\frac{4}{3}((a^2+1)E(1/a)+(a^2-1)K(1/a))$$
for $a\geq1$ in the paper, where $K$ and $E$ are the first and second kind of complete elliptic integrals respectively. But for me this integration is not clear since if I do the integration for $x$ first then it results in a term with natural log which is irrelevant to elliptic integral, and doing it for $\theta$ first results in the terms including $E(\frac{4ax}{(a-x)^2})$ and $K(\frac{4ax}{(a-x)^2})$ which seems hard to be reduced to $E(a)$ and $K(a)$. What approach would give the most clarified evaluation? Any advice or help will be appreciated.

Comment: strange...Have u checked there result numerically?

Comment: a small addition: i doubt that u can exchange integration limits freely here because the integral is singular for some choices of parameters (for example $\Theta=0, a<0$) and one has to be a little bit carefule

Comment: I would try the change of variables $x\sin\theta=aw$ and $x\cos\theta=at$.

Comment: a quick check in mathematica suggests that the results they obtained are incorrect. For example setting $a=1.5$ i obtain $2.95567$ using NIntegrate and a value of $11.1862$ using the result they give. values of $a$ lead to similar descripancies

Comment: @tired Thank you for you check. But I think the claimed evaluation value should not exceed $\pi$ for any value of $a$. (There is a graph for it in the paper above)

Comment: @tired Oh, I misinterpreted the graph. I'm sorry.

Comment: Using a semianalytic approach, i claim that
$$
I(a)=\frac{(a-1) \left(\left(a^2+1\right) E\left(\frac{\pi }{4}|-\frac{4 a}{(a-1)^2}\right)+\left(a^2+1\right) E\left(\frac{3 \pi }{4}|-\frac{4 a}{(a-1)^2}\right)+(a+1)^2 \left(-\left(F\left(\frac{\pi }{4}|-\frac{4 a}{(a-1)^2}\right)+F\left(\frac{3 \pi }{4}|-\frac{4 a}{(a-1)^2}\right)\right)\right)\right)}{3 a}
$$

which might be further simplified (but not by mathematica)

Comment: sory latex messed it up. Everything except of the $3a$ should be in the numerator. The above expression also yields results consistent with the numeric evaluations

Comment: @tired Oh, thanks a lot! Maybe one can find an expression including the complete elliptic integral equivalent to your result. I will try.